# path homotopy inverses

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Given $(X,\tau)$ a topological space.  Prove that $f \ast \bar{f}$ is path homotopic to $e_{x_0}$.

Where $f:[0,1] \to X$ a continuous path $f(0)=x_0$ and $f(1)=x_1$ with $\bar{f}(s)=f(1-s)$.  Now $e_{x_0}(s)=x_0$ for all $s\in [0,1]$.  We need to show that $F:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to X$ is continuous and satisfies the following  \begin{align} 
F(0,t)&=x_0 \\  F(1,t)&=x_1 \\F(s,0)&=f \ast \bar{f} (s) \\ F(s,1)&=e_{x_0}(s)
\end{align} for all $s,t \in [0,1]$.
I dont know how to draw pictures here so I will give my idea.  $$$$ 
For $0\le s \le \frac{1-t}{2}$ we want the F to be in terms of $f$. I arrived at this because I drew a line between the points $(0,1)$ and $(\frac{1}{2},0)$. Then it is constant for $\frac{1-t}{2} \le s \le \frac{1+t}{2}$. Finally we have F in terms of $\bar{f}$ for $\frac{1+t}{2} \le s \le 1$ and I got $\frac{1+t}{2}$ by looking at the line through points $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ to $(1,1)$. $$ $$ Now here is where I am experiencing the most difficulty.  I have tried the following $\theta:[0,\frac{1-t}{2}]\to [0,1]$.  I chose $[0,1]$ because original $f:[0,1] \to X$. So $\theta(0)=0$ and $\theta(\frac{1-t}{2})=1$. I find the slope$$\frac{1-0}{\frac{1-t}{2}-0}=\frac{2}{1-t}.$$  Now I solve for $\theta(s)=\frac{2}{1-t}s+b$. To solve for $b$ I plugin $0$ to get $$\theta(0)=0+b \implies b=0.$$ Which gives me $f(\frac{2s}{1-t})$ for  $0\le s \le \frac{1-t}{2}$ Similarly for $\lambda:[\frac{1+t}{2},1] \to [0,1]$ and $\bar{f}:[0,1]\to X$.  For $\lambda(\frac{1+t}{2})=1$ since $\bar{f}(1)=x_1$ and $\lambda(1)=0$ we again find the slope $$\frac{0-1}{1-\frac{1+t}{2}}=\frac{-2}{1-t}.$$  Now $$\lambda(1)=0=\frac{-2}{1-t}+b \implies b=\frac{2}{1-t}.$$  Therefore we have $
  F(s,t) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   f(\frac{2s}{1-t}) & \text{if $0\le s\le \frac{1-t}{2}$} \\
                                   f(t) & \text{if $\frac{1-t}{2}\le s \le \frac{1+t}{2} $} \\
  \bar{f}(\frac{-2}{1-t}s+\frac{2}{1-t}) & \text{if $\frac{1+t}{2} \le s \le 1$}
  \end{cases}
$

However, this formula for $F$ can't be right, because for $t=1$ it is not even well-defined because it involves dividing by zero.  So my question is, how can I fix this?  If you could explain your work specifically how you got your $f(?)$ in $F$ that would be greatly appreciated cause I am really struggling with this.

Comment: @EricWofsey clearly my $F(s,t)$ is not correct at $t=1$ because I would have $0$ in the denominator.  I am struggling in how to compute the values inside the $f$ in $F(s,t)$.

Answer (score 1):

We may define i: I → I to be the identity map, i¯: I → I to be i¯(s) = 1-s and e: I → I to be e(s) = o for all s∈I. Then we may define H: IxI → I by H(s,t) = (1-t)(i∗i¯)(s)+te(s) for all (s,t)∈IxI. Since I is a convex subset of real numbers, H is well defined. Then you may check f。H is a path homotopy between f∗f¯ and ex0.